# Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 10, 10, 10, 10)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build CNN. I got stuck here.

```
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
x_test shape: (10000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
```

```
y_train dimensions (60000, 10, 10, 10, 10)
y_test dimensions (10000, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,199,882
Trainable params: 1,199,882
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=3,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3b73f30a94ae> in <module>
      4 
      5 model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=3,
----> 6           validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
      7 score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
      8 print('Test loss:', score[0])

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

please do me a favour in this and
How to debug such error in these libraries.
would you also suggest how to get started with building CNN? like professional way.
Any sources would be greatly appreciated.
Please provide me with some insight into how to build custom CNN's and custom loss function and custom activation function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at your labels' shape (y_train & y_test). they have 4 dimensions. but your last dense layer classifies your data into one of 10 classes which means that it has 2 dimensions. Therefore, your output shape doesn't match your labels shape. If you are following a tutorial or something please update it with the link so we can know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code you use to preprocess your labels (`y_train`, `y_test`)? Why are your labels 5-dimensional? Usually they are 2-dimensional when using one-hot-encoding.

Here's a introductory blogpost about Convolutional Neural Networks:

https://medium.com/intuitive-deep-learning/build-your-first-convolutional-neural-network-to-recognize-images-84b9c78fe0ce

There are tons of good blogposts like this, just google for it. If your are serious you can consider buying a book, that's what I did when I started learning about Neural Networks. For the beginning custom loss functions and custom activation functions are not needed.